# Is it possible to make commands in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, command

I was thinking of whether it was possible to have a command-line interface in HTML, with some CSS or script whatsoever. Like you type a command and it does a function like revealing text or something.

Comment: "_Is it possible to make commands in HTML?_" No. - "_with some CSS or script whatsoever_" Yes.

Comment: yes so can you tell me how that's possible through CSS?

Comment: Not CSS. CSS is only for styling. This is only possible through JavaScript. And there are many different approaches you can take. It depends a bit on how exactly you want it to work. In its current state, this question is way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [nearley.js?](https://nearley.js.org/docs/index)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok so a little update on this. I got the code to make a working command system on my half developed web OS, basically its just some js for answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here's an update for the JS. I'm gonna find a way to have it perform a hide/unhide action upon typing "run [insert name]"

```js
function getInput() {
  return document.getElementById("answer").value;
}

var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", mySubmit);

function mySubmit() {
  var text;
  var database = [{
      answer: "help",
      clue: "info, credits, run"
    },
    {
      answer: "info",
      clue: "made by: SkyKrye"
    },
    {
      answer: "credits",
      clue: "StackOverflow, W3Schools, Discord"
    },
    {
      answer: "run",
      clue: "unspecified program: run [insert program name]"
    }
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
    if (database[i].answer === getInput()) {
      text = database[i].clue;
      console.log(text);
    }
  }

  if (!text) {
    text = "Syntax Error";
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = text;
}
```

```css
  button {
  font-family: consolas;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #111;
  box-shadow: #111;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 26px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    font-family: consolas;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inputField" id="answer" placeholder="Enter command" required>
<button id="submit" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).